# How should I get JSGridControl using Javascript in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, gantt-chart

I’ve tried the ‘hook’ as shown below and found in other posts:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function()
{
var oldGanttControl = SP.GanttControl;
SP.GanttControl = function()
{
oldGanttControl.call(this);
var oldInit = this.Init;
this.Init = function(jsGridControl, jsRawGridData, params)
{
oldInit.call(this, jsGridControl, jsRawGridData, params);
DoCustomizations(jsGridControl);
};
};
},"SPGantt.js");

Function DoCustomizations(grid)
{
  //etc etc
}
```

However this seems to work only for SP2010. With SP2013 I get an error saying:

“SCRIPT438: Object doesn’t support property or method ‘WaitForGanttCreation’
sp.ui.timeline.debug.js, line 3335 character 13″

Is there a solution for this to work on a Gantt View in SP2013 ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try that:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function()
{
    var oldGanttControl = SP.GanttControl;
    SP.GanttControl = function() {
        oldGanttControl.call(this);
        var oldInit = this.Init;
        this.Init = function(jsGridControl) {
            oldInit.apply(this, arguments);
            DoCustomizations(jsGridControl);
        };

        for (prop in oldGanttControl) {
            if (oldGanttControl.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                SP.GanttControl[prop] = oldGanttControl[prop];
            }
        }

    };
},"SPGantt.js");

Function DoCustomizations(grid)
{
  //etc etc
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't bother with the native SharePoint Gantt chart. I would take a look at this one: http://intelligantt.blogspot.com/2015/01/minimum-intelligantt-for-sharepoint.html

Comment: This won't work for Quick Edit list view (datasheet view) where SP.GanttControl is used too.